# Visualforce action function issue with 2 select lists on same page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two picklists in my code.  On selection of one of this i need to redirect to respective page.So if i select a value in first picklist i go to page 1 and if i select another i go to page 2.below is my visualforce page

```
<td>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:actionFunction name="getpickvalueandredirect" action="{!redirectuser}" />
        <apex:selectList styleClass="greyButton" value="{!agencyselected}" size="1" onchange="getpickvalueandredirect();">                        
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!agencypick}"   />                        
        </apex:selectlist>
     </apex:actionRegion>   
</td>
<td>OR</td>
<td>
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:actionFunction name="getpickvalueandredirect2" action="{!redirectuser}" />
        <apex:selectList styleClass="greyButton" value="{!catselected}" size="1" onchange="getpickvalueandredirect2();">                       
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!categoriespick}"/>                       
        </apex:selectlist> 
    </apex:actionRegion>    
</td>
```

and this is my visualforce controller code

```
public ID agencyselected{get;set;}
public ID catselected{get;set;} 

public ApexPages.PageReference redirectuser(){

     ApexPages.PageReference page;

     if(agencyselected!=null){
         page = new PageReference('/apex/page1?Agency='+agencyselected);         
     }
     if(catselected!=null){
         page = new PageReference('/apex/page2?Category='+catselected);            
     }       

     page.setRedirect(true);
     return page;
}
```

For some reason both of them doesnt work together.Anyclue why

Comment: Have you tried creating two different methods for each actionFunction?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a few things:

1. Break the page redirects into two methods, one for each VF page.
2. Convert the visualforce to use actionSupport rather than actionFunction (just cleaner in my opinion)
3. Instead of using new PageReference, use Page.YourPageName as this helps you maintain namespaces in managed packages if you ever go down that path, and it's a better practice than hardcoding the VF path.
4. Take a close look at actionRegion and how it's affecting your rendering.  Sometimes actionRegion may interfere with populating the correct variables or rerendering the page depending on how it is used.

I've provided a working example of the select lists below.  I modified your VF to use a pageBlock instead of HTML table, but it should help you regardless.

Controller:

```
public class SelectTest{

    public String catselected {get;set;}
    public String agencyselected {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> categories {get; private set;}
    public List<SelectOption> agencies {get; private set;}

    public SelectTest(){
       categories = new List<SelectOption>();
       categories.add(new SelectOption('test1','test1'));
       categories.add(new SelectOption('test2','test2'));

       agencies = new List<SelectOption>();
       agencies.add(new SelectOption('test1','test1'));
       agencies.add(new SelectOption('test2','test2'));
    }

    public PageReference redirectToAgency(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Page1;
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Agency',agencyselected);
        return pageRef;
    }

    public PageReference redirectToCategory(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Page2;
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Category',catselected);
        return pageRef;
    }

  }
```

Visualforce:

```
  <apex:page controller="SelectTest">
      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                  <apex:selectList value="{!catselected}" size="1" styleClass="greyButton">                       
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!categories}"/>                       
                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirectToCategory}" />
                  </apex:selectList>
                  <apex:outputText value="OR" />
                  <apex:selectList value="{!agencyselected}" size="1" styleClass="greyButton">
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!agencies}"/>                       
                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirectToAgency}" />
                  </apex:selectList>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<td>
   <apex:selectList styleClass="greyButton" value="{!agencyselected}" size="1" onchange="getpickvalueandredirect();">                        
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!agencypick}"/>                        
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirectuser}" />
   </apex:selectlist>

 </td>
  <td>
       OR
 </td>
 <td>

 <apex:selectList styleClass="greyButton" value="{!catselected}" size="1" onchange="getpickvalueandredirect2();">                       
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!categoriespick}"/>                       
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirectuser}" />
 </apex:selectlist> 
  </td>
```